# Error "Uncaught TypeError" when changing this object propety- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am learning about objects and prototypes in JavaScript and I got stuck.
My aim is to create an object which then gets drawn onto a page. I have created another prototype constructor so later the this specific created object can be moved on a page however it doesn't work and I don't know how to progress further with it

here is my JS:

```
var Bunny = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Bunny.prototype.drawBunny = function () {
    var bunnyImage =  document.createElement('img');
    bunnyImage.src = "https://64.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m06yweMXBl1qaajuxo1_500.gif";
    bunnyImage.style.position = "absolute";
    bunnyImage.style.left = this.x + "px";
    bunnyImage.style.top = this.y + "px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(bunnyImage);
}

Bunny.prototype.moveRight = function() {
    this.x += 5;
    this.bunnyImage.style.left = this.x + "px";
    this.bunnyImage.style.top = this.y + "px";
}
```

and then in console log (this works):

```
var sunflower = new Bunny(200, 200);
sunflower.drawBunny();
```

but when I write this in console log:

```
sunflower.moveRight();
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.bunnyImage is undefined

pointing at `this.bunnyImage` in `moveRight()` function

Comment: Your `this.bunnyImage` is undefined

Comment: Your code never creates a `bunnyImage` property on the object. The `var` variable in `drawBunny` does **not** do that; you have to set `this.bunnyImage` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "It doesn't work" (this statement alone is not enough to help). In your case, the console says :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Indeed, `this.bunnyImage` is undefined. You forgot to store it in your function with `this.bunnyImage = bunnyImage;`

```js
var Bunny = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Bunny.prototype.drawBunny = function() {
  var bunnyImage = document.createElement('img');
  bunnyImage.src = "https://64.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m06yweMXBl1qaajuxo1_500.gif";
  bunnyImage.style.position = "absolute";
  bunnyImage.style.left = this.x + "px";
  bunnyImage.style.top = this.y + "px";
  this.bunnyImage = bunnyImage;
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(bunnyImage);
}

Bunny.prototype.moveRight = function() {
  this.x += 5;
  this.bunnyImage.style.left = this.x + "px";
  this.bunnyImage.style.top = this.y + "px";
}

var sunflower = new Bunny(200, 200);

sunflower.drawBunny();
sunflower.moveRight();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was making this challenge from a book and I wasn't sure what bunnyImage is. Also thanks for a tip, I have forgotten to add error message.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var Bunny = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Bunny.prototype.drawBunny = function () {
    this.bunnyImage =  document.createElement('img');
    this.bunnyImage.src = "https://64.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m06yweMXBl1qaajuxo1_500.gif";
    this.bunnyImage.style.position = "absolute";
    this.bunnyImage.style.left = this.x + "px";
    this.bunnyImage.style.top = this.y + "px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(this.bunnyImage);
}

Bunny.prototype.moveRight = function(delta = 5) {
    this.x += delta;
    this.bunnyImage.style.left = this.x + "px";
    this.bunnyImage.style.top = this.y + "px";
}

var sunflower = new Bunny(200, 0);
sunflower.drawBunny();

// Lets dance
setInterval(() => {
  sunflower.moveRight(200 * (.5 - Math.random()))
}, 200)
```

Comment: Answers are much more useful with an explanation of what needed to be changed or improved, and why you chose to do things the way you did.